# Mysql update fields only if both fields are null at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, null

I re-written the complete question because I was not clear enough the first time.

I am trying to update a given row id in users table and fill only values that are null, like this:

```
UPDATE USERS SET
address='Main Street' IF current address IS NULL
gender='M' AND full_name='JOHN SMITH' IF both gender and full_name ARE NULL
job='Mechanic' IF current job is NULL
WHERE id=123
```

I don't know how to do the part with updateing both gender and full_name, I want the other fields to still trigger and update individually regardless of the `gender` and `full_name` values

Comment: Sidenote: You are quoting those variables where they stand to be strings, correct? You also tagged as php but there really isn't any code to support the question, other than the variables.

Comment: yes, just the variables came from PHP

Answer (score 3):

This might be a verbatim answer to your question:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET gender = $gender,
    full_name = $full_name
WHERE gender IS NULL AND full_name IS NULL
```

However, it seems to make more sense to update a record if *either* the gender or full name be `NULL`.  In this case, you can try:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET gender    = COALESCE(gender, $gender),
    full_name = COALESCE(full_name, $full_name)
WHERE gender IS NULL OR full_name IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough, I tried to add more details now, I cannot use `WHERE gender and full_name IS NULL` at the end because I already have an `WHERE id=123` and also because other fields are updated individually on other conditions (if they are null).

Comment: Why would already having a term in the `WHERE` clause preclude adding more terms?  In any case, the two options I gave you is how I would do this.

Comment: would an order like this be valid (that location of null gender and full_name) ? `UPDATE users SET address='Back Stteet', (gender='m', full_name='foo' WHERE gender=null AND full_name=null), job='mechanic' WHERE id=123`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, sorry.

Comment: In above comment... I would like it to still update things like `address` and `job` regardless of `gender` and `full_name`, but with your answer (`WHERE gender IS NULL OR full_name IS NULL` at the end) the full update will only trigger if the two are null.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` in `update` statement in `SQL` gets into the `WHERE` part of the query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET gender = $gender WHERE gender IS NULL AND full_name IS NULL
```

> I would add also `AND id = $id_you_want_to_update`

Comment: you forgot `gender IS NULL AND full_name IS NULL` that was the question. Only update if both are null.